# A function to convert null to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a function to convert any null value e.g. from a database to an empty string.
I know there are methods such as if `value != null ?? value : String.Empty` but is there a way to pass `null` to a method e.g.

```
public string nullToString(string? value)
{
    if(value == null) return empty;
    return value
}
```

But I am not sure on the parameter syntax to do this.

I tried the above but it says not a nullable type.

Comment: You say "e.g. from a database"; is this your actual use case? And what are you using to read from a database? This will determine whether you are dealing with Null or a DBNull value and will help guide our answers.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `string?`. Strings are reference types.

Comment: The built-in [`Convert.ToString(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) method converts both `null` and `DBNull` to an empty string.

Comment: I prefer to handle nulls at database level with a COALESCE function.

Comment: Adding on @MichaelLiu, note that directly passing a null to `Convert.ToString` results in a null value, so that `Convert.ToString(null) == null` returns true, but `object v = null; Convert.ToString(v) == string.Empty` returns true.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
static string NullToString( object Value )
{

    // Value.ToString() allows for Value being DBNull, but will also convert int, double, etc.
    return Value == null ? "" : Value.ToString();

    // If this is not what you want then this form may suit you better, handles 'Null' and DBNull otherwise tries a straight cast
    // which will throw if Value isn't actually a string object.
    //return Value == null || Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)Value;


}
```

Comment: I found this answer helpful. So, thanks for answering this.

Answer (score 34):

When you get a NULL value from a database, the value returned is DBNull.Value on which case, you can simply call `.ToString()` and it will return `""`

Example:

```
 reader["Column"].ToString()
```

Gets you `""` if the value returned is `DBNull.Value`

If the scenario is not always a database, then I'd go for an Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static string EmptyIfNull(this object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string someVar = null; 
someVar.EmptyIfNull();
```

Comment: The value is not always from a database.

Comment: This will work (though see comment in my answer regarding int, double, etc); but I never really liked the idea of Extension methods when dealing with Null - that is it looks like you're calling a method on Null which should throw an exception. I know why it works, but it just looks 'wrong', IMO.

Comment: @GarethWilson I completely agree with you in that calling a method on NULL should throw an Exception but in some cases this is helpful. To alleviate things a bit, you can add method documentation to at least warn the user of this behavior.

Comment: @Icarus may I suggest `EmptyIfNull` as a better name?

Answer (score 28):

[`Convert.ToString(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) converts to string. If the object is `null`, `Convert.ToString` converts it to an empty string.

Calling [`.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) on an object with a null value throws a [`System.NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

EDIT:

Two exceptions to the rules:

1) `ConvertToString(string)` on a null string will always return null.

2) `ToString(Nullable<T>)` on a null value will return "" .

Code Sample:

```
// 1) Objects:

object obj = null;

//string valX1 = obj.ToString();           // throws System.NullReferenceException !!!
string val1 = Convert.ToString(obj);    

Console.WriteLine(val1 == ""); // True
Console.WriteLine(val1 == null); // False


// 2) Strings

String str = null;
//string valX2 = str.ToString();    // throws System.NullReferenceException !!!
string val2 = Convert.ToString(str); 

Console.WriteLine(val2 == ""); // False
Console.WriteLine(val2 == null); // True            


// 3) Nullable types:

long? num = null;
string val3 = num.ToString();  // ok, no error

Console.WriteLine(num == null); // True
Console.WriteLine(val3 == "");  // True
Console.WriteLine(val3 == null); // False 

val3 = Convert.ToString(num);  

Console.WriteLine(num == null);  // True
Console.WriteLine(val3 == "");  // True
Console.WriteLine(val3 == null); // False
```

Comment: This will return a null if the value passed to it is a null string instead of a null object.

Comment: @Stephen: That makes sense because we don't use Convert.ToString(object) to convert a null string to an empty string. The purpose of this function is to convert any object to a string; so if the object is null (regardless the object is a string or not), it will return a null string.

Comment: Except Nullable<T>. Check this sample: http://rextester.com/NST67691. `.ToString()`... When Nullable<T> is null returns empty string.

Comment: Edited to add exceptions.

Answer (score 18):

You can just use the null coalesce operator.

```
string result = value ?? "";
```

Comment: In the example value is of type string.

Comment: neither of us is correct: in the example, the impossible type `string?` is used.

Comment: Seems to work for me:  `((object)null) ?? ""` returns `""`

Answer (score 11):

Its possible to make this even shorter with C# 6:

```
public string NullToString(string value)
{
    return value?.ToString() ?? string.empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I just append an empty string to an object that might be null.

```
object x = null;
string y = (x + "").ToString();
```

This will never throw an exception and always return an empty string if null and doesn't require if then logic.

Comment: It's a good solution... quick, well documented and easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
public string nullToString(string value)
{
    return value == null ?string.Empty: value;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Convert.ToString((object)value)`. You need to cast your value to an object first, otherwise the conversion will result in a null.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string format = "    Convert.ToString({0,-20}) == null? {1,-5},  == empty? {2,-5}";
        object nullObject = null;
        string nullString = null;

        string convertedString = Convert.ToString(nullObject);
        Console.WriteLine(format, "nullObject", convertedString == null, convertedString == "");

        convertedString = Convert.ToString(nullString);
        Console.WriteLine(format, "nullString", convertedString == null, convertedString == "");

        convertedString = Convert.ToString((object)nullString);
        Console.WriteLine(format, "(object)nullString", convertedString == null, convertedString == "");

    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Convert.ToString(nullObject          ) == null? False,  == empty? True 
Convert.ToString(nullString          ) == null? True ,  == empty? False
Convert.ToString((object)nullString  ) == null? False,  == empty? True
```

If you pass a System.DBNull.Value to Convert.ToString() it will be converted to an empty string too.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the "?." (null conditional member access) with the "??" (null-coalescing operator) like this:

```
public string EmptyIfNull(object value)
{
    return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

This method can also be written as an extension method for an object:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string EmptyIfNull(this object value)
    {
        return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And you can write same methods using "=>" (lambda operator):

```
public string EmptyIfNull(object value)
    => value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Extension methods rock, but also are quite interesting. I have a variable that is set to null, although this extension method still works: `string test = null; test.EmptyIfNull();` returns ""!

Answer (score 1):

you can use ??""
for example:

```
y=x??""
```

if x isn't null y=x but if x is null y=""

Answer (score 1):

**1. string.Format**

You can use `string.Format` which converts null to empty string

```
string nullstr = null;
string  quotestring = string.Format("{0}", nullstr);
Console.WriteLine(quotestring);//Output- ""
```

**2.string interpolation**

or you can use `string interpolation.` this feature is available in C# 6 and later versions.

InterpolatedExpression produces a result to be formatted. A string representation of the null result is `String.Empty`.

```
 string nullstr = null;
 string  quotestring = $"{nullstr}";
 Console.WriteLine(quotestring);//Output- ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string ToString(this string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }               
            else
            {
                return value.Trim();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an old topic, but there is a "elegant" way to do that...

```
static string NullToString( object Value )
{       
    return Value = Value ?? string.Empty;    
}
```

Comment: No, that code does not even compile. You mean static object NullToString

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public string ToString(this object value)
{
    // this will throw an exception if value is null
    string val = Convert.ToString (value);

     // it can be a space
     If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Trim()) 
         return string.Empty:
}
    // to avoid not all code paths return a value
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Would a convert throw an exception? I thought it would be an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

you can use null-coalescing-operator C# 8.0 and later

value ??=string.Empty;

[??= operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a nullable string to string.

```
string? input = "kushal";

string output = input?.ToString() ?? ""
```

Answer (score -3):

According to the following [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netcore-3.1), you need the `Convert.ToString` method

```
string x = Convert.ToString((object)value)
```

Comment: This is the same as [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412497/215552) left 6 years ago.